# Splice Machine master installation produces error on HDP 2.6.4

Tags: ambari, hdp, splice-machine

I'm trying to intall Splice Machine Master service 2.7 using Ambari on HDP 2.6.4.
All the prerequsites listed in this document https://github.com/splicemachine/spliceengine/blob/branch-2.7/platforms/hdp2.6.4/docs/HDP-installation.md are verified and Active hBase Master is installed on the same node.
But I have the following error on service startup:

```
INFO 2018-12-26 18:03:39,286 PythonReflectiveExecutor.py:67 - Reflective command failed with exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/PythonReflectiveExecutor.py", line 59, in run_file
    imp.load_source('__main__', script)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/SPLICEMACHINE/2.5.1/package/scripts/splice_install_master.py", line 97, in <module>
    SpliceInstallMaster().execute()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 375, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/SPLICEMACHINE/2.5.1/package/scripts/splice_install_master.py", line 32, in status
    import params
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/SPLICEMACHINE/2.5.1/package/scripts/params.py", line 81, in <module>
    immutable_paths = get_not_managed_resources(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/functions/get_not_managed_resources.py", line 36, in get_not_managed_resources
    not_managed_hdfs_path_list = json.loads(config['hostLevelParams']['not_managed_hdfs_path_list'])[:]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
   obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
```

TypeError: expected string or buffer

Why it might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug (broken python script). Maybe dependant on your cluster configurations. I suggest asking at https://community.hortonworks.com/index.html